# RowNum in Mysql, with group by (MySQL 5.x)

Tags: mysql

I would like to do a rownum in MySql but using the group by. So the rownum need to start again when de column city change.

I tried that:

```
> select city, category_name, sales,    @row_number:=CASE WHEN
> @db_names=sub_table.city THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number
> from ( SELECT city, category_name, sum(subtotal) as sales from
> customers     join orders on customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
>     join order_items on orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
>     join products on order_items.product_id = products.product_id
>     join categories on products.category_id = categories.category_id
>     group by city, category_name
>     ) sub_table ORDER BY sub_table.city ASC, sub_table.sales DESC;
```

But I got this result:

[image]

Comment: MySQL 5.x or 8.x? Easy in 8.x.

Comment: unfortunately MySQL 5.x

Comment: Could you provide some sample data, to test your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, just the variable @db_name not assigned value:

```
select city, category_name, sales,    
  @row_number:=CASE WHEN
    @db_names=sub_table.city THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,
  @db_name:=sub_table.city
from ( SELECT city, category_name, sum(subtotal) as sales from
customers     join orders on customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
    join order_items on orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
    join products on order_items.product_id = products.product_id
    join categories on products.category_id = categories.category_id
    group by city, category_name
) sub_table ORDER BY sub_table.city ASC, sub_table.sales DESC;
```

Comment: But here the row_number still being 1 all the time. :(  , I Know I am forgetting something, but I can't find what!

Answer (score 1):

i  programmed it like other query i made here on SO.

You should also use aliases for your tables.

```
 SELECT 
    `city`,
    `category_name`,
    `sales`
     ,IF(@db_names = city , @row_number:= @row_number + 1  , @row_number:= 1 ) AS row1_number
     ,@db_names := city
FROM
    (SELECT 
        city, category_name, SUM(subtotal) AS sales
    FROM
        customers
    JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
    JOIN order_items ON orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
    JOIN products ON order_items.product_id = products.product_id
    JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.category_id
    GROUP BY city , category_name
    ORDER BY city , category_name) sub_table
    ,(SELECT @dab_names := '') c1,(SELECT @row_number := 0) d1
ORDER BY sub_table.city ASC , sub_table.sales DESC;
```

Without a sampe to test it properly it is

Comment: tks for your help, I really forgot the aliases, but here the row1_number still always being 1!

Comment: Post your data as text or as dbfiddle and i look into it.